# What does an interface with CIDR /32 mean?

Tags: networking

I am used to seeing ip addresses of the form 10.244.0.1/24. What does an address cidr notation /32 mean ?

```
$ ip a
...snipped...
4 : flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1410 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default                                                           
[4/401]
    link/ether 06:fb:8c:da:42:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.244.0.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4fb:8cff:feda:420b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: It means the subnet mask is `255.255.255.255` (or that it is the only IP in it's network)

Comment: It is new to me that an address ending in .0 is a valid IP. I am familiar with class C addresses in which if the last octet is 0, it is used to refer to the network. I'm such an ignoramus.

Comment: `.0` being a valid IP is new to me as well, don't feel bad :p

Comment: A `.0` address isn't always the network address, and the network address doesn't always end in `.0` (it's always the first address in the subnet).  e.g. in a /23 network, the subnet spans from x.x.x.0 to x.x.x+1.255 - there is a valid `.0` address in the middle of that.    BTW, address classes have been obsolete for well over 20 years now - obsoleted by Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR), the standard "address/prefix" used everywhere now.

Comment: In the [RFC4632 table at the end of section 3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4632#section-3.1) a /32 address is called a host route and is defined with a value of `n.n.n.n` meaning (IMhO) that it can have any value. [This is also related](https://serverfault.com/a/10989).

Comment: Even if you stick to class-based routing, 10.0.0.0/8 is a class A. But yes, the first IP is often left unassigned to clients, the last one is of course the broadcase address (and often by convention the gateway is put on the next-to-last IP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means all the subnet mask bits are "ON" and the subnet mask for that IP address is `255.255.255.255`.

Comment: A setup now commonly found in scenarios such as the one in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299580/ .