# FreeBSD on VPS unable to connect to the internet; interface appears configured

Tags: networking, freebsd, configuration, routing, vps

I've recently installed the raw virtual image of FreeBSD 12.1-STABLE onto a VPS provided through OVH.  I'm able to login via the KVM on my control panel, but the machine is unreachable by SSH.  It turns out that's because the machine isn't able to connect to the internet.

I'm able to ping the interface `vtnet0` at its given IPv4 address, but `# ping 8.8.8.8` or any `# ping6` returns some form of "no route to host".

Here is the output for `# ifconfig -a`:

[image]

And here is the output of `# netstat -rn`:

[image]

And here's the content of `/etc/rc.conf`:

[image]

Section 11.5 of the Free BSD handbook has led me to believe that the NIC is configured, but at this point I'm not really sure what to change or investigate to get online. Any guidance is appreciated.

**Update (5 Apr. 2020):**  I've managed to get my VPS online, thanks largely to the contributor with the selected answer, help from the FreeBSD forums, and [this article by Tim Chase](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwix5_aXs9LoAhVnhq0KHd3PCH4QFjADegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftim.thechases.com%2Fposts%2Finstalling-freebsd-on-ovh%2F&usg=AOvVaw3q2bT4TbVHFqc1SoHUQ8yu).

My solution eventually entailed reinstalling Debian, the running `# apt install network-manager` followed by `# nmcli device show ${INTERFACE_NAME}` to get the necessary network information assigned to my machine by OVH by default, then reinstalling FreeBSD and configuring `/etc/rc.conf` like so:

```
ifconfig_vtnet0="inet $EXTERNAL_IPv4 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast $EXTERNAL_IPv4"
static_routes="net1 net2"
route_net1="$GATEWAY_IPv4 -interface vtnet0"
route_net2="default $GATEWAY_IPv4 "
ifconfig_vtnet0_ipv6="inet6 $EXTERNAL_IPv6 prefixlen 64"
ipv6_defaultrouter="$GATEWAY_IPv6"
```

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: Make sure you start sshd. `service sshd start` (or possibly `onestart`, or `restart`).

Comment: The `sshd_enable="YES"` in the question achieves that.

Comment: @JoeBP Only after restart. You must start the service manually otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OVH configuration is actually quite simple, and is the same for IPv4 and IPv6:

- You apply the given IPv4 address with a /32 prefix length, or the given IPv6 address with a /64 prefix length, to the network interface, statically.
- You set the default IPv4 and IPv6 gateways to the IPv4/IPv6 addresses that OVH specifies, which are determined in predictable and documented ways from the /24 prefix of your *host* IPv4 address or the /56 prefix of your IPv6 address.
- You set up a static route telling your machine how to route to the default gateway's IP address.

The third part is important.  The OVH-supplied IP gateway is (intentionally) not in the same subnets as your own IPv4/IPv6 addresses, so that your LAN IP broadcast traffic is excluded.  Effectively, the connection between you and the rest of Internet is a two-host LAN where the second host is not implicitly routable (by IPv4 mechanisms), so has to have an explicit route.

This is the same for all operating systems, and simply varies in the ways that individual operating systems set it up.  In "[OpenBSD with only a /32 repeatedly deletes its static route to the world](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299580/5132)", as you can see, the OpenBSD way is the normal default IP gateway stuff plus an extra route in `/etc/hostname.vio0`.

The FreeBSD way is settings in `/etc/rc.conf`:

- a `ifconfig_vtnet0` that statically assigns the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, with an IPv4 `netmask 255.255.255.255` or an IPv6 `prefixlen 64`
- `defaultrouter` and `IPv6_defaultrouter` settings giving the IP addresses of the respective gateways
- (for IPv4, since IPv6 can discover the route) a static route to the gateway, configured as (for example) `wibble` added to the value of `static_routes` and a (consequently named) `route_wibble` setting with `-net`, the gateway address and the IP address of the `vtnet0` interface

Notice that DHCP is not involved.  You can retain that `ifconfig_DEFAULT`, as long as you have a *specific* `ifconfig_vtnet0` that supersedes it.

## Further reading

- `man rc.conf`
- *[Configuring IPv6 on dedicated servers](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-ipv6/)*.  OVH.
- coltondrg? (2017-04-20). *[FreeBSD VMs on your OVH hypervisor](https://wpa.coltondrg.xyz/2017/04/freebsd-vms-on-your-ovh-hypervisor/)*.  wpa.coltondrg.xyz.

Comment: Actually, since the IPV6 gateway is not in the network of the IPv6 address, you have to set up IP address with "prefixlen 56" so IPV6 gateway is "reachable".